# sqlite database not saving data into table

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, cordova

I need to use sqlite for my phonegap app for iOS, and I found this working sample online. However when I integrate it to my app, when I click Add Record or Refresh button, nothing happens. The database is not updated and no data is added. The example says to add query.min.js for the code to work and that's what I did.

Javascript code:

```
var db; 
var shortName = 'WebSqlDB'; 
var version = '1.0'; 
var displayName = 'WebSqlDB'; 
var maxSize = 65535; 

function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
        alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);

    }

    function successCallBack() {
        alert("DEBUGGING: success");

    }

    function nullHandler(){};

    function onBodyLoad(){

        alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");

        if (!window.openDatabase) {

            alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
            return;
        }


        db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName,maxSize);


        db.transaction(function(tx){


                       //tx.executeSql( 'DROP TABLE User',nullHandler,nullHandler);


                       tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FirstName TEXT NOT NULL, LastName TEXT NOT NULL)',[],nullHandler,errorHandler);},errorHandler,successCallBack);

    }

    function ListDBValues() {

        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
            return;
        }


        $('#lbUsers').html('');


        db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                       transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM User;', [],
                                              function(transaction, result) {
                                              if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                                              for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                              var row = result.rows.item(i);
                                              $('#lbUsers').append('<br>' + row.UserId + '. ' + row.FirstName+ ' ' + row.LastName);} } },errorHandler); },errorHandler,nullHandler);

                       return;

    }


    function AddValueToDB() {

        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
            return;
        }

        db.transaction(function(transaction) {
                       transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?)',[$('#txFirstName').val(), $('#txLastName').val()], nullHandler,errorHandler); });


                       ListDBValues();

                       return false;

    }
```

Html:

```
<body onLoad="onBodyLoad()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <input id="txFirstName" type="text" placeholder="FirstName">
        <input id="txLastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
            <input type="button" value="Add record" onClick="AddValueToDB()">
                <input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="ListDBValues()"> <br>
                    <br>
                    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Currently stored values:</span>
                    <span id="lbUsers"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Could try out this sample available in the github page - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_SQLite

Comment: It still doesn't work with the new codes. When I click create, insert or fetch button nothing happens

Comment: the samples are tested on android devices and it works. Could you inspect it on safari for any console errors?

Comment: there's no console errors on the web inspector... but the buttons are still not working.

Comment: You got it working? Cos got a comment from kerryf88 in my github page on this.